# Send Email from worker role (Azure) with attachment in c#

Tags: email, azure, send, role, worker

I am trying to send an email(in c#) from worker role(Azure) with an attachment(from blob storage).
I am able to send an email but attachment(word document) is blank.
The following function is called from worker role.

```
    public void sendMail(string blobName)
    { 
            InitStorage();//Initialize the storage
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString");
            container = blobStorage.GetContainerReference("Container Name");
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

            if (File.Exists("demo.doc"))
                File.Delete("demo.doc");

            FileStream fs = new FileStream("demo.doc", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            blob.DownloadToStream(fs);                
            Attachment attach = new Attachment(fs,"Report.doc");
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage Email = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("User@hotmail.com", "User@gmail.com");
            Email.Subject = "Text fax send via email";
            Email.Subject = "Subject Of email";
            Email.Attachments.Add(attach);
            Email.Body = "Body of email";
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 25);
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User@hotmail.com", Password);
            client.Send(Email);
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
            Email.Dispose();                       
    }
```

Please tell me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I would try do `fs.Position = 0;` before attaching creating your `Attachement` object.

What's probably happening is that it's trying to read from current position in the stream and that stream is at the end, so it reads nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but you should probably be calling fs.Close() *before* sending the email.

Comment: Got the solution
byte[] file= blob.DownloadByteArray();
Attachment attach = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(file), "Report.doc");



Instead of using FileStream used Byte array and MemoryStream and its working fine.

Thanks for your replies.